# C# WPF Database Exercise How to update database column

Tags: c#, wpf, database, linq, dataset

Doing a learning exercise.
Trying to update the database date column for all entries to a new specific value or go through each entry and change date to a new specific value.
I tried using DataContext & Linq but it keeps telling me missing reference which its not so I have reverted to this.

```
        var results = webDataSet.GreyList;
        foreach (var elements in results)
        {
            elements.Date = 55;
        }
        webDataSet.AcceptChanges();
        greyWebTableAdapter.Update(webDataSet.GreyList);
```

Even If i put Update in a try catch it says it is successful but it will never update the database.

Plus I'd like to thank the people who have nothing to say yet down vote my questions, its people like you who really bring the community together.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How do you update a database column or specific entry value from a database using datasets

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else who took advice to add .AcceptChanges(); by using this it sets the dataSets modified row value from true to false; so when you update the method looks for modified true row's however they are all false so nothing gets updated. Also the other factor to not seeing the database change is because Visual studio 2015 creates a copy of the database from your local folder and duplicates it in your bin folder, so looking for changes in your local folders database is a waste of time.